# Unexpected output while using const_cast<>

Tags: c++, const-cast

I have written below code my machine(devcpp) and codepad.org  but on my matching is working fine and on codepad.org(http://codepad.org/XfW5a8en) the output is a garbage characters.

> ```
>    #include <iostream>
>     #include<cstring>
>     using namespace std;
>     int main () {
>         char *str1 =const_cast<char*>(string("Hello ").c_str());
>         char *str2 = const_cast<char*>(string("World!").c_str());
>         char *ptr = str1;
>         char *&rptr = str1;
>         rptr = str2;
>         std::cout << ptr << str1 << std::endl;
>     }
> ```

I am expecting the output as
Hello World!

Comment: `string("Hello ")` and `string("World!")` are temp objects, destroyed after the `;` at their own lines.

Comment: I'm not up to date with the latest standards, but IMHO in the old days (prior to C++ 0X) that code used to expose undefined behaviour because the pointer returned by `c_str()` was only valid as long as the object it was obtained from lived, and `string("Hello ")` creates a temporary that might already be destructed at the site of your `std::cout`.

Answer (score 7):

When you say `string("Hello ")` without storing it anywhere, the string can be destroyed at the end of the expression that creates it.

You're taking a pointer to the memory that was owned by that destroyed string, which may or may not keep the value of `"Hello "` for some amount of time afterwards, but it's undefined whether that will happen, or for how long.

It's only working on your machine because sometimes "undefined behaviour" means "looks like it works".  :-)

Comment: Pedantically, it can't be "instantly" destroyed. It lasts until the end of the full expression that creates it, but no longer.